# Query about generalization table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

okay I have some table like this..

```
table TopicForum
-------------------------
 - idforum (PK)
 - iduser (FK)
 - subject
 - content


table Usermember
--------------------------------
-iduser (PK)
-password
-accesslevel

table student
-------------------------------
-idstudent (PK)
-iduser (FK)
-name

table teacher
---------------------------------
-idtecher (PK)
-iduser(FK)
-name

table admin
-----------------------------------
-idadmin (PK)
-iduser(FK)
-name
```

so I want show **name**  in TopicForum reference by **iduser** in **student** , **teacher**, and **admin**..

please help thanks

Comment: Can, e.g., a single user be both a teacher and an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.name, A.iduser 
FROM (SELECT NAME, iduser FROM Student
      UNION 
      SELECT NAME, iduser FROM Teacher
      UNION
      SELECT NAME, iduser FROM Admin) AS A 
INNER JOIN TopicForum tf ON A.iduser = tf.iduser
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT tf.Subject
FROM TopicForum tf
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT iduser FROM Student
    UNION 
    SELECT iduser FROM Teacher
    UNION
    SELECT iduser FROM Admin
) u ON tf.iduser = u.iduser
```

I don't quite understand why you make a distinction between `iduser` and `idteacher` for instance. Unless you want to format them a certain way (but why ?) I would suggest merging those two columns in a unique id column, which can be a one to one relation to the `usermember` table.